# Spring Security Authentication-Authorization at field level

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security. I have implemented Spring Security authentication and authorization at page level for my application(Like Admin only can access Admin page and normal user can't).
But now my requirement is to apply read-write authorization at field level. Some of the fields can be edited by only Admin and whereas for others it is read-only. The remaining fields in the page are common for all.
Is there any way to do solve this please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you need to allow access to only certain CRUD methods like updateProduct() only if the user updating the product is an ADMIN?

Comment: Hi Abdullah, Can we make a field readable or writable based on the user role using security tag library or any other spring security mechanism.
And to access certain CRUD methods as per the role we can use method level security(annotations like @PreAuthorize) if I am not wrong.

Comment: Hi @VamsiKrishna  Did you find a solution to this issue. If so can you please share it that would be helpful.